# how to create database by copying .db file from asset folder to database folder using phonegap api in android

Tags: android, cordova

i want to do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434367/copy-my-own-sqlite-db-from-asset-folder-to) but using phonegap api in android

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap has its own [support Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap), which is the place you should turn to first for PhoneGap questions. Here is a [recent post over there](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_frm/thread/5e57a728dc66a2a1) on this topic.

Upshot: Right now, you cannot do this except by modifying the hosting Android app (`DroidGap.java`).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try
        {
            String pName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
            this.copy("Databases.db","/data/data/"+pName+"/databases/");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException {
        File CheckDirectory;
        CheckDirectory = new File(folder);
        if (!CheckDirectory.exists())
        { 
            CheckDirectory.mkdir();
        }

        InputStream in = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder+file);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len; while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) out.write(buf, 0, len);
        in.close(); out.close();

    }
}
```